# How to understand the juniper's chassis concept?

Tags: router, juniper, networking

I searched a chassis article which is introducing the Chassis.

[MX960 Chassis](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/release-independent/junos/topics/concept/chassis-mx960-description.html)

It's a physical concept there, but I think the `chassis` is far more than this.
because if we in the commands:

[image]

there shows many information.

so how to understand the `chassis` correctly?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, when referring to the "chassis" it's almost always going to imply the physical chassis, rather than the configuration statements from your question.

That being said, the chassis configuration statements are settings that directly relate to the chassis and the installed components within (FPC, SCB, RE, Craft Interface, etc.)

Here are a couple of examples that will hopefully provide some additional context.

1. [Network Services](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/concept/network-services-mode-overview.html)

Network services configuration has to do with how certain hardware-related features are either enabled/disabled or scaled.  This can also determine if certain types of physical hardware components (typically line cards) are enabled/disabled as well.

```
root@vmx6# set chassis network-services ?
Possible completions:
  enhanced-ethernet    Enhanced ethernet network services
  enhanced-ip          Enhanced IP network services
  ethernet             Ethernet network services
  ip                   IP network services
```

2. [Routing Engine Redundancy](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/task/configuration/routing-engine-redundancy-configuring.html)

Routing engine redundancy settings allow you to determine what happens when the hard drive on a routing engine experiences an issue.  With these, you can tell a routing engine to shut off entirely or perhaps just reboot.

```
root@vmx6# set chassis redundancy failover ?
Possible completions:
+ apply-groups         Groups from which to inherit configuration data
+ apply-groups-except  Don't inherit configuration data from these groups
  disk-read-threshold  Read threshold (ms) on disk underperform monitoring (1000..10000)
  disk-write-threshold  Write threshold (ms) on disk underperform monitoring (1000..10000)
  not-on-disk-underperform  Prevent gstatd from initiating failovers in response to slow disks
  on-disk-failure      Failover on disk failure
  on-loss-of-keepalives  Failover on loss of keepalives
```